# How to unhide columns with a script in Excel online

Tags: excel, typescript

It's a shared Excel file so I can only use Typescript and no macros.

I'm working with some Excel online automation scripts. I hide and unhide columns with the help of several scripts. One of the scripts is intended to unhide columns a:bx. Since I don't know what script this script is coming after, first, just in case, I hide all the columns:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active worksheet
    const currentSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    // Hide columns A to XFC
    const columnsToHide = currentSheet.getRange("a:XFC");
    columnsToHide.setColumnHidden(true);

    // Unhide columns A to BX
    const columnsToUnhide = currentSheet.getRange("A:BX");
    columnsToUnhide.setColumnHidden(false);

}
```

After running this script, some columns (BI:BH) are hidden, and I can't even unhide them manually, it's like the program thinks it's unhidden but it's hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unhide columns with a script in Excel online, you need to use the following steps:

Open the Excel file in Excel online.
Click on the Developer tab.
Click on the Visual Basic button.
In the Visual Basic Editor, right-click on the VBAProject pane and select Insert Module.
In the new module, paste the following code:
Kódrészlet

```
Sub UnhideColumns()    
    ' Get the active worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Unhide columns A to BX
    Dim columnsToUnhide As Range
    Set columnsToUnhide = ws.Range("A:BX")
    columnsToUnhide.Hidden = False    
End Sub
```

Legyen körültekintő a kód használatakor. További információ.
Click on the Run button to run the macro.
This should unhide columns A to BX. However, if some of the columns are still hidden, you can try the following:

Click on the Home tab.
In the Cells group, click on the Format button.
Click on Visibility.
Click on Unhide Columns.
In the Unhide Columns dialog box, select the columns that you want to unhide and click on the OK button.
This should unhide the remaining columns.